# Как закрыть блок по второму клику?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет. У меня есть кнопка бургер-меню с анимацией. Вот пример https://codepen.io/sequelone/pen/OOromj

А вот мой JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var toggles = jQuery('.cmn-toggle-switch');

    toggles.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

   var bsDefaults = {
         offset: false,
         overlay: true,
         width: '330px'
      },
      bsMain = $('.bs-offset-main'),
      bsOverlay = $('.bs-canvas-overlay');

   $('[data-toggle="canvas"][aria-expanded="false"]').on('click', function() {
      var canvas = $(this).data('target'),
         opts = $.extend({}, bsDefaults, $(canvas).data()),
         prop = $(canvas).hasClass('bs-canvas-right') ? 'margin-right' : 'margin-left';

      if (opts.width === '100%')
         opts.offset = false;

      $(canvas).css('width', opts.width);
      if (opts.offset && bsMain.length)
         bsMain.css(prop, opts.width);

      $(canvas + ' .bs-canvas-close').attr('aria-expanded', "true");
      $('[data-toggle="canvas"][data-target="' + canvas + '"]').attr('aria-expanded', "true");
      if (opts.overlay && bsOverlay.length)
         bsOverlay.addClass('show');
      return false;
   });

   $('.bs-canvas-close, .bs-canvas-overlay').on('click', function() {
      var canvas, aria;
      if ($(this).hasClass('bs-canvas-close')) {
         canvas = $(this).closest('.bs-canvas');
         aria = $(this).add($('[data-toggle="canvas"][data-target="#' + canvas.attr('id') + '"]'));
         if (bsMain.length)
            bsMain.css(($(canvas).hasClass('bs-canvas-right') ? 'margin-right' : 'margin-left'), '');
      } else {
         canvas = $('.bs-canvas');
         aria = $('.bs-canvas-close, [data-toggle="canvas"]');
         if (bsMain.length)
            bsMain.css({
               'margin-left': '',
               'margin-right': ''
            });
      }
      canvas.css('width', '');
      aria.attr('aria-expanded', "false");
      if (bsOverlay.length)
         bsOverlay.removeClass('show');
      return false;
   });
});
```

Нужно при клике по кнопке открывать канвас меню и при повторном нажатии закрывать. Сейчас работает только открытие.

А вот кнопка, по которой отдельно закрывается канвас меню.

```
<header class="bs-canvas-header p-3 bg-white overflow-auto">
        <button type="button" class="bs-canvas-close float-left close" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="text-dark">&times;</span>
        </button>
</header>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121011/jquery-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e/1121016#1121016 ?

Comment: сейчас привел пример до рабочего https://codepen.io/sequelone/pen/OOromj У меня идёт анимация и открытие меню по клику и через toggleClass. Нужно также приводить в исходное положение меню гамбургер при клику на затемнёное поле или overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.navbar-toggler').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('.navbar-toggler').toggleClass('active');
      $('.bs-canvas-overlay').toggleClass('show');
      $('.bs-canvas').toggleClass('active');;
      return false;
    })
});
```

Также есть и другой вариант:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   let bsDefaults = {
      offset: false,
      overlay: true,
      width: '330px'
   };

   let bsMain = $('.bs-offset-main');
   let bsOverlay = $('.bs-canvas-overlay');

   $('.nav-link-collapse').on('click', function() {
      $('.nav-link-collapse').not(this).removeClass('nav-link-show');
      $(this).toggleClass('nav-link-show');
   });

   let documentMenu = {
      isOpen: false,
      hamburgerToggle: () => {
         if (documentMenu.isOpen === false) {
            $('.cmn-toggle-switch').addClass("active");
            // documentMenu.open();
         } else {
            $('.cmn-toggle-switch').removeClass("active");
            // documentMenu.close();
         }
         documentMenu.isOpen = !documentMenu.isOpen;
      },

      open: () => {
         documentMenu.hamburgerToggle();

         let canvas = $('[data-toggle="canvas"][aria-expanded="false"]').data('target'),
             opts = $.extend({}, bsDefaults, $(canvas).data()),
             prop = $(canvas).hasClass('bs-canvas-right') ? 'margin-right' : 'margin-left';

         if (opts.width === '100%')
            opts.offset = false;

         $(canvas).css('width', opts.width);
         if (opts.offset && bsMain.length)
            bsMain.css(prop, opts.width);

         $(canvas + ' .bs-canvas-close').attr('aria-expanded', "true");
         $('[data-toggle="canvas"][data-target="' + canvas + '"]').attr('aria-expanded', "true");
         if (opts.overlay && bsOverlay.length)
            bsOverlay.addClass('show');
         return false;
      },

      close: () => {
         documentMenu.hamburgerToggle();

         let canvas, aria;
         let object = $('.bs-canvas-close, .bs-canvas-overlay');
         if ($(object).hasClass('bs-canvas-close')) {
            canvas = $(object).closest('.bs-canvas');
            aria = $(object).add($('[data-toggle="canvas"][data-target="#' + canvas.attr('id') + '"]'));
            if (bsMain.length)
               bsMain.css(($(canvas).hasClass('bs-canvas-right') ? 'margin-right' : 'margin-left'), '');
         } else {
            canvas = $('.bs-canvas');
            aria = $('.bs-canvas-close, [data-toggle="canvas"]');
            if (bsMain.length)
               bsMain.css({
                  'margin-left': '',
                  'margin-right': ''
               });
         }
         canvas.css('width', '');
         aria.attr('aria-expanded', "false");
         if (bsOverlay.length)
            bsOverlay.removeClass('show');
         return false;
      }
   };

   $('.cmn-toggle-switch').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if (documentMenu.isOpen === false)
         documentMenu.open();
      else
         documentMenu.close();
   });

   $('.bs-canvas-close, .bs-canvas-overlay').on('click', function() {
      documentMenu.close();
   });
});
```

Comment: можете посмотреть к чему я пришёл, что-то похожее у меня, вроде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1122468/331312